# How to disable the limit in Firebase phone authentication?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use `FirebaseUI/Phone` pod to register to the application, I entered the number, but the SMS did not come, I pressed the "Resend sms" button several times, but there was no result. After a few minutes, several sms came at once, but before that I had already restarted the application, after trying to log in again, I had the message "This phone number has been used too many times". Is there any way to turn it off for tests? How long does this warning go?

Comment: Have a look at this. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits

Comment: Well, I read, it follows that something needs to be changed in these restrictions, it is necessary to contact Firebase Support, it's unfortunate that I cannot configure it myself, because to increase the limit in one of the projects had to wait three days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it sounds like you're hitting limits that are in place to protect against abuse. If that is the case, the phone number should become usable again after some time. There's nothing you can do about it in the meantime.

If it doesn't become usable again after a day or so, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.